# How do I crop internal HTML elements at CSS3 rounded borders?

Tags: html, css

I have a div inside another div. The outer div has rounded borders using CSS3. The problem is, if I set a background color on the inner div it bleeds through into the corners. Here's a test page to show what I mean: http://www.webdevout.net/test?0O

I suspect it's not a renderer issue, as the same thing happens in Chrome, FF, and Opera. How do I get the inner div to crop at the rounded borders? Setting border-radius on the inner div to inherit doesn't cut it, the borders don't match up.

EDIT: The inner div is actually a header for more content inside the outer div, so applying the rounded borders to the inner div instead will not work.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the answer you're looking for, but try adding padding to the outer div.  That might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you set the rounded corners on your inner div and just use your outer div as the container (unless it's no longer needed, then just get rid of it to remove the unnecessary nesting).

See this example: http://www.webdevout.net/test?0Q

I added padding to your inner div and applied all of your CSS classes to the inner div.

Comment: Unfortunately not, as the inner div is actually a header to more content below it; I've simplified things for this example. If a better solution doesn't present itself I may be able to fake it with partial borders and rounded corners on all the inner objects, though.

Comment: You will likely need to add a lesser degree of rounding to your inner divs then (See example: http://www.webdevout.net/test?0R). As an additional note, the webkit rounding classes are no longer required for Chrome/Safari)

Comment: @Xavi Adding padding to the outer div and setting the background-color to the same as the inner div should also work.  Why didn't I think of that?

Comment: I was hoping there was some CSS command or something I was missing that would fix this, but I guess there isn't. Padding the outer div might work elsewhere, but here the header will be a different color than the content, so that won't work. Rounding the inner div to match the outer one seems like a bit of a kludge to me, but it seems to be the best solution, so I'll go with this one.

Comment: @BitLooter Agreed. Definitely not the ideal solution.  Hopefully future versions of HTML/CSS will support the inherit property cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Those areas are occupied by the border of the element and that can't be changed. That's not to say you can't without extra markup and css to pull it off but, normally, no.

Answer (score 0):

Round your top corners on the inner div but don't round the bottom corners, like so:

http://www.webdevout.net/test?0T

Answer (score -1):

overflow:hidden should do it... Or actually, it doesn't... give another set of rounded corners to the inside container.

Comment: As you say, overflow:hidden doesn't work, and rounding the inner container isn't good enough because the corners don't line up perfectly.

Comment: @BitLooter - fiddle with the border radius and you can get the inner corners to line up correctly